# Bug in R's ggplot2 characters in VS Code

Tags: r, ggplot2, visual-studio-code

```
a <- data.frame(
    x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    y = c(5, 5, 7, 3, 5))
```

I'm new to VS Code and I'm testing R 4.0.1 in this IDE. I used to use RStudio to do this kind of thing. This worked very well in Rstudio.

I came across a problem when I went to make graphics, the characters are weird for some reason.

```
install.packages('ggplot2')
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(a) +
    geom_col(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    ggtitle('My title')
```

Figure obtained:
[image]

Figure wanted:

[image]

How could I fix this?

Comment: Can you try with `+ labs(title = 'My title')` instead of `ggtitle`

Comment: I tried this, but got the same result

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE (2/2021): I updated my R version from 3.6 to 4.0 and this problem was fixed. My R graphics window no longer shows weird characters! In case this doesn't work for you, see below:

@Ben Bolker suggests trying `png()` or `CairoPNG()` (with `Cairo` package) as well.

Original:
I had the same problem happen to me and I'm using Sublime Text plus Rscript in my Linux terminal.  Unfortunately, I haven't found a fix for it yet only a workaround.

Here's what I do:
Use the [pdf](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/grDevices/versions/3.6.2/topics/pdf) function to save the plot as a pdf.  Then if you need it saved as a png or jpg, you can take a screenshot of the pdf.  I know it's not very elegant, but it's worked for me so far.

```
a <- data.frame(
    x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    y = c(5, 5, 7, 3, 5))

library(ggplot2)
myplot <- ggplot(a) +
    geom_col(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    ggtitle('My title')

pdf("myplot_filename.pdf")
print(myplot)
dev.off()
```

[image: Resulting plot as a png (using screenshot)]

Comment: For PNGs, you could try (1) the `png()` device; (2) `library(Cairo); CairoPNG(...)`, either of which (if they work) would be better than PDF + screenshot ...

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. In my case I tried them both and they didn't work and was stuck with pdf()..

Comment: OK.  Just thought I'd suggest it.